# Where is Tampermonkey's "Storage" tab to edit the storage content?

Tags: tampermonkey

According to the [FAQ](https://www.tampermonkey.net/faq.php) of Tampermonkey:

> Q400: I want to edit/view the values stored by a userscript. How can I
> do that?
>
> A400: Open Tampermonkey's Dashboard and click at the script's name.
> Click at the 'Storage' if present and check or modify the stored data
> as needed. If there is no 'Storage' tab, then the script has no data
> stored.

**I can't find the Storage tab**, can anyone confirm me it works? Screenshot of where is the tab? (pretty sure my script has data stored in it because when I use `GM_getValue` I get something).

Here is a screenshot of my script without the Storage tab. After running it, the value is stored according to my console.log, but still no tab.

[image]

Comment: You should put the text of that script in the question as well as the screenshot.  With the text, the question would then have a proper [mre].

Comment: @BrockAdams MCVEs/MREs are only required for debugging questions. Since this is not a debugging question, it does not require one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Requirements for the *Storage* tab to appear:

1. The script has must have actually saved a datum using `GM_setValue()`.
2. The *Config mode* must be set to `Advanced`:

[image: Config mode]

After that,

#### To see it:

1. Open Tampermonkey's editor on/for the script in question.
2. Click the *Storage* tab.
3. Data there is in JSON format.  If you edit it, recommend checking with [a JSON validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) before hitting the *Save* button.

Here's the sequence in screenshots (Click for a larger image):

[image: opening the storage viewer]

Comment: @PerrierCitror, See the updated answer and check `Config Mode`.  If that still doesn't work: (1) Did you refresh the tab with the Tampermonkey editor in it? Close the tab and open a new one.  (2) Next, try installing the Beta Tampermonkey version for Chrome and test that.  (3) Next, switch to Firefox and try that edition of Tampermonkey.